# How to access child object color material in collisionEnter function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

having problem with my game with unity.

I have a player object and 
I have a parent object with 8 of child objects.

I randomised the color material of the child objects. and the player color material as well.

the i want to detect whether my player material color == child object material color inside the collisionEnter function.

i tried many, but it didn't work
here is the code 
Thank in advance guys

```
// I access the child object in SetRandomColor.cs 
void Start()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in parentCircle.transform)
        {
            int i = Random.Range(0, 8);
            if (child.gameObject.name == "Bar")
            {
                jumlahBar++; // kita sudah tau jumlah Bar ada berapa
                Debug.Log(jumlahBar);
                rendCircle = new Renderer[jumlahBar];
                rendCircle = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
                Debug.Log("this is the: " + rendCircle[i].material.color);
            }
        }
    }




// then i tried to access the color of the child objects in my Player.cs 
// here the code, i tried this, but turn error 

  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Color> == player.gameObject.GetComponent<Color>)
        {
            Debug.Log("saya warna sama");
        }
    }

// Error '==' can be used in method group`enter code here`
```

Comment: You are missing the () for the GetComponent. But Color is not a component or did you create a new Color class? In this case, you could have namespace clash as well. You need to access the Renderer which contains the material with the assigned color, just like you did in the Start above. But if you are colliding with the parent object, looking for the component in children will return the first found, and you said there were 8 of them. You need to collide with the child objects.

Comment: @Everts I'm glad you said something about the multiple different children with different colors. I overlooked that at first haha.

Comment: @FernandoSinaga How is the color of the player determined? Is the color of the player guaranteed to be the same value of one of the children? I'm wondering if you need a check for exact equality or approximate equality.

Comment: Thanks, no i don't collide player with th parent object, the parent object just an empty game object.. I don't create a new color class. and yes the player object collides with the child object. I have tried with the code @Ruzihm gave me to a new project where all color are manually assined to my child object and player. it work fine. but when I tried with my actual project it did'nt work. is that because I randomise the color iI think? Thank once again.

Comment: the child objects and the player colors are randomized to 4 colors, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and Green. i assign same material to child objects and player object. so it should be no problem with the equality for both material and color. Thanks @Ruzihm

Answer (score 1):

`Color` isn't a component, so you should get the `Renderer` component and look at the color of its material. Also, you forgot the `()` at the end of the `GetComponentInChildren<...>()` method call.

Also, convert the colors to `Vector4` so that it compares the values of the color components.

As Everts suggested, you'll want to give each child object a collider if you want to check the color of specifically the child you collided with. So, just use `GetComponent`, not `GetComponentInChildren`.

Also, you should call `GetComponent` as few times as possible and remembering the result where you can, because it is an expensive operation:

```
private Renderer playerRenderer;

void Start() 
{
    playerRenderer = player.GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Renderer collidedRenderer = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    if (collidedRenderer != null && 
            (Vector4)collidedRenderer.material.color ==
            (Vector4)playerRenderer.material.color
            )
    {
        Debug.Log("saya warna sama");
    }
}
```

---

### Your clarification above means that you won't need to do this, but I am going to go ahead and leave it here because it could be useful for other people...

If your colors are randomly determined in a way that you should only wait for a "close enough" color, compare the squared distance vs a "close enough" distance.

```
private Renderer playerRenderer;
private float closeColorSquareDistance = 0.01f;

void Start() 
{
    playerRenderer = player.GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Renderer collidedRenderer = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    if (collidedRenderer != null && 
            (   (Vector4)collidedRenderer.material.color
              - (Vector4)playerRenderer.material.color
            ).sqrMagnitude < closeColorSquareDistance
            )
    {
        Debug.Log("saya warna sama");
    }
}
```

You'll need to find a value of `closeColorSquareDistance` that makes the comparison work for you. Decrease `closeColorSquareDistance` to make the comparison more strict, and increase it to make the comparison more lenient.

Comment: Thank a lot @Ruzihm, i tried couples of time but it didn't work. not because the logic is incorrect i think, since i have tried with new project, a simpler one. the code is working well. that's because i assign color to my child object manually and player color as well. i assign all colors to my child and parent objects manually. and the code you gave is working smooth. but when i tried with my actual project it didn't work, since i randomise the child objects color.

Comment: @FernandoSinaga I realized I made a mistake in how to compare `Color`s. Try that. Also depending on exactly how you randomize the child colors, you may never get exact matches so you'll need a way to check for "close enough" matches. I've included code for that as well.

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm, it work well with my other project. superb. But i figure out that with my actual project it doesn't work, that happens because the colliders of my child objects don't touch to my player sphere collider. so that's the problem. need help and advice how to fi my mesh collider of my triangle pizza-like child objects. Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

```
Color myColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
Color barColor = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;

        if (myColor.IsEqualTo(barColor))
        {
            Debug.Log("saya warna sama");

            score = score + 1;
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best") < score)
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Best", score);

            textscore.text = "" + score.ToString();
        }

==================================================================

The Extension class and method:


public static bool IsEqualTo(this Color me, Color other)
    {
        return me.r == other.r && me.g == other.g && me.b == other.b && me.a == other.a;
    }
```

Comment: I found this quite handy. Thanks for helping me guys. Cheer